# Как создать файл, размер которого составляет 80 - 90 процентов от свободного места на android девайсе?

Tags: android, bash, shell

Пытаюсь использовать следующую последовательность команд

`BYTE="m" ; eighteen=$(for SPACE in $(adb shell df | awk '{print$4}'| tail -1) ; do expr $SPACE / 100 \* 90; done) ; truncate -s $eighteen$BYTE file_8; adb devices -l ; read -p "Введите ID или IP адрес и TCP порт девайса :" ID ; adb -s $ID push ./file_8 /sdcard/`

но файл file_8 создается не того размера, который мне требуется - то есть вместо гигабайт создаются мегабайты.

Comment: [программой truncate вы создаёте разрежённый файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1005157/178576). вам же, судя по вашим вопросам, требуется всё-таки **заполненный** (хоть чем-нибудь) файл.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/609024/454489

Comment: Не совсем понятно для чего тут цикл, если берется последнее значение. Так же по умолчанию df выводит размер в килобайтах, следовательно нужно переводить в мб `aaa=$(df | awk '{print$4,$NF}'| tail -1); eighteen=$(($(echo $aaa | awk '{print $1}')/1024/100*90)); dir=$(echo $aaa | awk '{print $2}'); cd $dir; truncate -s $eighteen$BYTE file_8`